# ipython: display large output line-by-line, instead of vertically

Tags: ipython

I want to display a large output of an ipython command line-by-line on the screen, instead of in a column. Now I have:

`In [9]: range(25)
Out[9]: 
[0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13,
 14,
 15,
 16,
 17,
 18,
 19,
 20,
 21,
 22,
 23,
 24]`

I want to have like in python terminal:

`>>> range(25)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]`

Comment: Use print. `print(range(25))`

Comment: You haven't said how your printed the first result, so I assume you are using simply `print`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Comment: my question is about ipython, not python. How to change the settings in ipython so that it displays like python